# Placing images in entries (Friggeri CV)

Tags: graphics, positioning, cv, friggeri-cv

Sorry for another Friggeri CV-related question, this is the last one. I feel like the solution should be really easy with tikzpicture nodes, but I just cannot make it work...

I am using [Friggeri's CV template](https://github.com/afriggeri/cv) with the same `friggeri-cv.cls` (I have only changed all the Helvetica fonts to Arial and added `backend=biber` to the `\RequirePackage{biblatex}` line).

What I would like is to place the university logos (the logo is [this one](http://isis.roma1.infn.it/~presilla/logo_sapienza.gif), but any image will do) between the 3 lines of text, not at the top. The relevant lines I have been playing with in the `friggeri-cv.cls` file are the following:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% List environment %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{11.8cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}
```

And my MWE is the following:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}
\listfiles
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}


\begin{document}
\header{name}{surname}
       {occupation}

% In the aside, each new line forces a line break
\begin{aside}
  \section{about}
    aaa
    bbb
\end{aside}


\section{background}

\begin{entrylist}
  \entry
    {1991}
    {MSc {\normalfont in this and that}}
    {\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{logo.png}}
    {{\thinfont Specialized in this and that}\\
    Honorary Mention}
  \entry
    {1993}
    {PhD {\normalfont in other stuff}}
    {\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{logo.png}}
    {{\thinfont Specialized in other stuff}\\
    Honorary Mention}
\end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

Which produces [image: this]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The images are all set to rest on the baseline. You can maneuver them up or down using a combination of `\smash` and `\raisebox` commands. The former removes any impact on the vertical displacement that stems from moving it up/down. The latter is used to move it up or down.

Try, for example,

```
\smash{\raisebox{-\height}{\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{logo_sapienza}}}
```

[image]

<sub>I don't have *Helvetica Neue* on my machine.</sub>